How do I configure vs for c?
I have been learning c language lately. To Run my programs I've been using an online compiler but i wanted to try out vs code. Hence I started by installing Vs code and all the extensions for c which include(c/c++, code runner, cmake, ctools, c/c++ extension pack). After this I installed MingGW from sourceforge which I have added to my path. So i am able to compile and run programs from cmd. But I am not able to do so from Vs code. I have attached a screen shot below. Please help me configure it, as I am unable to figure out the issue.

Added mingw\bin to my Path.
Vs code added to my path
Configured MinGW\bin\gcc.exe as my default build task.
There is a task.json file in my .vscode folder which was generated by vs code itself.
Tried Reinstalling vs code and MinGW from multiple sources and Multiple times.
Tried Manually compiling and running my scripts through cmd, Which works.


follow the C/C++ tutorial in the VSC doc, come back with the steps that fail

The VS Code doc is your first stop. But VS 2022 is probably a much better environment to learn C/C++ as it is a primary focus of the product. I got VS Code working with C++ after quite a lot of configuring, but things were much easier after installling and using VS 2022.
